# Retrieve a value by another column criteria in R

Tags: r

i need some help:

i got this df:

```
df <- data.frame(month = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
             day   = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
             flow  = c(2,5,7,8,5,4,6,7,9,2))

   month day flow
1      1   1    2
2      1   2    5
3      1   3    7
4      1   4    8
5      1   5    5
6      2   1    4
7      2   2    6
8      2   3    7
9      2   4    9
10     2   5    2
```

but i want to know the day of min  per month:

```
   month day flow dayminflowofthemonth
1      1   1    2                    1
2      1   2    5                    1
3      1   3    7                    1 
4      1   4    8                    1
5      1   5    5                    1
6      2   1    4                    5 
7      2   2    6                    5
8      2   3    7                    5
9      2   4    9                    5
10     2   5    2                    5
```

this repetition is not a problem, i will use pivot fuction

tks people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `which.min` to return the index of 'min'imum 'flow' per group and use that to get the corresponding 'day' to create the column with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
       group_by(month) %>% 
       mutate(dayminflowofthemonth = day[which.min(flow)]) %>%
       ungroup
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   month   day  flow dayminflowofthemonth
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>                <dbl>
# 1     1     1     2                    1
# 2     1     2     5                    1
# 3     1     3     7                    1
# 4     1     4     8                    1
# 5     1     5     5                    1
# 6     2     1     4                    5
# 7     2     2     6                    5
# 8     2     3     7                    5
# 9     2     4     9                    5
#10     2     5     2                    5
```

Comment: PERFECT. but can i ask something? how i get two days after the min value? if "4" is the dayminflowofthemonth, i want to retrieve "1", e.g. (i will use this for months with 30/31 days, so it need to be in account)

Comment: @BryanSouza. Are the days always in a sequence?.  For the first 'month', you need `4` and if there is no exact match, i.e .you have 3 and 5, then which one should it return

Comment: @BryanSouza Also, for the second month, what would be the value of 'day' because 5 is the max 'day' in that

Comment: These days are the days of the year, so there is variation from month to month (30,31,28 days ...). I have a column with the days in sequence, so I need to "skip" 7 days in that column and get the value

Comment: @BryanSouza can you please update with a new example so that I can test it. thanks.  I was thinking `df %>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(dayminflowplus2 = min(max(day), day + 3))[which.min(flow)])

Comment: df <- data.frame(
             day = c(1:31, 1:30, 1:31),
             dayofmin = c(rep(28,31), rep(27,30), rep(29,31)),
             dayofmin.plus.7 = c(rep(4,31), rep(4,30), rep(NA,31))
             )

Want to get dayofmin.plus.7

Comment: @BryanSouza Do you have 'year' or 'month' column.  I think I understand your question.  If those columns are present, it is more easier

Comment: @BryanSouza that would make it easier.  Can you post that as a separate question with a complete example as it seems to be a bit different because of the way we need the computation.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another option using indexing inside `dplyr` pipeline:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(Val=day[flow==min(flow)][1])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   month [2]
   month   day  flow   Val
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     2     1
 2     1     2     5     1
 3     1     3     7     1
 4     1     4     8     1
 5     1     5     5     1
 6     2     1     4     5
 7     2     2     6     5
 8     2     3     7     5
 9     2     4     9     5
10     2     5     2     5
```

Comment: This is great, but if the first value (day1) is NA, this returns NA. (na.rm = True in min() doesn't work)

Answer (score 2):

One more base R approach:

```
df$dayminflowofthemonth <- by(
  df,
  df$month,
  function(x) x$day[which.min(x$flow)]
)[df$month]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  df,
  dayminflowofthemonth = ave(day*(ave(flow,month,FUN = min)==flow),month,FUN = max)
)
```

which gives

```
   month day flow dayminflowofthemonth
1      1   1    2                    1
2      1   2    5                    1
3      1   3    7                    1
4      1   4    8                    1
5      1   5    5                    1
6      2   1    4                    5
7      2   2    6                    5
8      2   3    7                    5
9      2   4    9                    5
10     2   5    2                    5
```